# Creating MoveListFactory with GenuineVariableDescriptor

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on a variant of the VRP Routing Problem with chained graphs.  I'm implementing a move that takes two entities on a chain, but are not a subchain themselves, and moves them to a new different chain.  This invloves a GenuineVariableDescriptor as shown here.

```
public ChangeVehicleMove(Object entity, GenuineVariableDescriptor variableDescriptor, Object toPlanningValue)
```

I'm using this move to implementing a custom MoveListFactory.  I'm having trouble generating a GenuineVariableDescriptor.  What is the best way to do this?

The move factory:

```
public class ChangeVehicleMoveFactory implements MoveListFactory{

    @Override
    public List<? extends Move> createMoveList(Solution solution) {
    List<Customer> customerList = ((RoutingSolution) solution).getCustomerList();
    Iterator<Customer> customerIterator1 = customerList.iterator(), customerIterator2 = customerList.iterator();
    List<Move> moveList = new ArrayList<Move>();
    Customer customer1, customer2;

    Class<?> c = ((RoutingSolution) solution).getCustomerList().getClass();
    GenuineVariableDescriptor genuineVariableDescriptor = null;

    try {
        genuineVariableDescriptor = new GenuineVariableDescriptor(new EntityDescriptor(new SolutionDescriptor(RoutingSolution.class), TimeWindowedCustomer.class), new FieldMemberAccessor(c.getField("previousStandStill")));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (genuineVariableDescriptor != null){
        while (customerIterator1.hasNext()) {
            while (customerIterator2.hasNext()) {
                customer1 = customerIterator1.next();
                customer2 = customerIterator2.next();
                if (customer1 != customer2 && !customer1.isAssigned())
                    new ChangeVehicleMove(customer1, genuineVariableDescriptor, customer2);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Another possibility is to include the move as part of the move list in the configuration.  There is very little documentation on this.  if this route is a better approach, how would you include that in the configuration file?

Comment: If you use a custom move, why do you need to have a VariableDescriptor? You know your domain model, why bother with reflection?

Comment: Here be dragons - go down this path at your own risk - don't do this at home: `InnerScoreDirector.getSolutionDescriptor().findEntityDescriptor(...).findVariableDescriptor(...)`